# Version number in dependencies

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-authentication

If I put the line `implementation ("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth")` without version number I will get warning:
`Failed to resolve: com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth`.

Everything goes fine if I put dependency with verson number - `implementation ("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.0")`

I was expecting Gradle to retrieve the latest version number when it is not defined. I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> I was expecting gradle to retrieve the latest version number when it is not defined. I'm wrong?

Yes, you're wrong. When you're using the [Firebase-UI library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android), you have to explicitly set the version in the implementation. If you omit that, you get that error.

When using [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth), you can [implement BOM](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) and Auth for example, without the need to specify the version:

```
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
```

Comment: Hey Vico. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?